# Write parquet file with Snappy compression in Apache Beam

Tags: parquet, apache-beam, snappy

I am trying to write a parquet file as follow in Apache Beam using Snappy compression

```
records.apply(FileIO.<GenericRecord>write().via(ParquetIO.sink(schema)).to(options.getOutput()));
```

I see that is possible to set `AUTO`,`GZIP`,`BZIP2`,`ZIP` and `DEFLATE` as compression but I am unable to find a way to set it as `SNAPPY`, any ideas how to do this? As reference, it is possible to do using wrting to avro as follow

```
records.apply("writeAvro", AvroIO.writeGenericRecords(schema).withCodec(CodecFactory.snappyCodec()).to(options.getOutput()));
```

Answer (score 2):

Good news!  Soon after your question, the `withCompressionCodec(...)` codec was [added](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-6302) to the ParquetIO sink.  This is available from Apache Beam 2.11.0 on.

You may have been looking at the FileIO.Write abstract classes that allow you to use `withCompression(Compression)`, which takes enum that does not include SNAPPY.  If it were used, it would compress the *entire* file with the specified compression type, which would be inappropriate for Parquet.  The method above specifies how to compress the row groups internally in the file.

Fortunately, the ParquetIO prevents you from making this mistake.  Only the correct compression configuration method is exposed.